# Are there single-word alternatives that indicate plagiarism of "ideas"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As per Wikipedia, plagiarism is "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work.

While there are words that depict plagiarism in the context of "literature" and/ or "art/ music" (e.g. piracy, appropriation, borrowing, counterfeiting, lifting, literary-theft, etc.), I was not able to think of single-word alternatives that indicate plagiarism of "ideas".

Do such alternatives exist, or should I simply refer to it as "idea plagiarism"?

Comment: Oops, the similarity to an existing question was unintentional/ accidental. My apologies. But noticed (now) that answers given for the original question did not provide any "well accepted" single-word alternatives.

Comment: "Ideas" is included in the definition of "plagiarism". Why doesn't that suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Intellectual property would generally cover the notion of a 'protected' or 'owned' idea, in a strictly formal sense (patents on inventions, mechanical/chemical processes, innovative and unique ideas (such as the rules and mechanics used in the trading card game Magic: The Gathering, which other TCG's are prohibited from using), software, copyrighted creative works (such as the Star Wars or LOTR universes, which must be licensed to be included and expanded in other media, such as books or video games), etc.

In this case, you could use **intellectual property theft**, which is a term used by the FBI.

Source: https://www.fbi.gov/investigate/white-collar-crime/piracy-ip-theft

For an informal notion, as in 'borrowing an idea used conceived of by someone else', I can't think such word to describe this other than appropriation (if the idea is not credited or attributed to it's originator), since an idea is immaterial and as such cannot be 'owned' the same way a material object, such as a publication or written text can be.